# syntax error in android

Tags: java, android, syntax

i wrote this method but keep getting an error saying:

Syntax error on token "int", @ expected

Syntax error, insert "EnumBody" to complete BlockStatement

```
@Override
public int calculateCurrency() 
{
    int[] currency = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.currenciesvalues);
    return Integer.parseInt((String) spinner1.getSelectedItem()) / Integer.parseInt((String)spinner2.getSelectedItem());
}
```

this is the full java class which the method is in.

```
package com.msc.conv;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CurrencyActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.currency);


final Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    final  Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
   final EditText etResult = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etResult);

ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.currencies, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){

//public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener{

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id){
        //String str = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
        //etResult.setText(str);

    }
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent){
        //Do nothing
    }



});

spinner2.setAdapter(adapter);
spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){

//public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener{

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id){
        //String str = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
        //etResult.setText(str);

    }
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent){
        //Do nothing
    }



});



final EditText editCurr = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etamount);
    Button convert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_convert);
     convert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v){
             double curr = Double.valueOf(editCurr.getText().toString());


                double result2 = Double.valueOf(spinner1.toString()) / Double.valueOf(spinner2.toString());
                double result = curr * result2;
                etResult.setText(String.valueOf(result));
         }
     });


        public int calculateCurrency() 
        {
            int[] currency = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.currenciesvalues);
            return Integer.parseInt((String) spinner1.getSelectedItem()) / Integer.parseInt((String)spinner2.getSelectedItem());//currenciesvalues[spinner2.getSelectedItemPosition()];
        }

    Button homeBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_currencyhome); 
    homeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub             
        startActivity(new Intent(CurrencyActivity.this, MainActivity.class));         
        }     
    });
}
```

}

Comment: When you created the class, did you create an Enum class?

Comment: Please give more context. This looks okay to me *in the right context*.

Comment: @buzcek no i did not create enum class, do i have to?

Comment: @akkki: We're just guess about everything until you show us the surrounding code. The problem may well be with *where* this code appears. Try removing the method body for example, just replacing it with `return 0;` (I note you're not actually using `currency` anyway...)

Comment: @JonSkeet if i remove the body and replace with return 0 i still get same problem

Comment: @akkki: Then clearly the problem isn't in the method body - it's in some of the code you *haven't* presented...

Comment: i added the whole class if it helps.

Comment: That's not the whole class.  Please edit and paste ALL of it.

Comment: @Simon posted everything in the class

Comment: @akkki: Now could you indent it properly and get rid of the commented out lines? It's *really* hard to read at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell as the code is badly formatted, but I *suspect* this statement is the problem (just above the code you originally posted):

```
convert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v){
        double curr = Double.valueOf(editCurr.getText().toString());
        double result2 = Double.valueOf(spinner1.toString()) / Double.valueOf(spinner2.toString());
        double result = curr * result2;
        etResult.setText(String.valueOf(result));
    }
});
```

That code doesn't belong to a method or constructor at all - it's just in the middle of the class. The only things that can be *directly* in a class are field declarations, methods, constructors, destructors, nested classes, and initializers.

I suspect you actually meant to put that in a constructor. Ditto the code at the end to do with `homeBtn`.

So as a shorter example, this code is invalid:

```
public class InvalidCode {
    private Button button = new Button();
    button.setText("Foo");
}
```

But this is valid:

```
public class ValidCode {
    private Button button = new Button();

    public Button() {
        button.setText("Foo");
    }
}
```